# How does this CSS produce a circle?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

This is the CSS:

```
div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 180px solid red;
    border-radius: 180px;
}
```

How does it produce the circle below?

[image]

Suppose, if a rectangle width is 180 pixels and height is 180 pixels then it would appear like this:

[image]

After applying border-radius 30 pixels it would appear like this:

[image]

The rectangle is becoming smaller, that is, almost going to disappear if the radius size increases.

So, how does a border of 180 pixels with `height/width-> 0px` become a circle with a radius of 180 pixels?

Comment: It's a 0x0 object with a 180 pixel border **around it** which has rounded corners. So the rounded corners are quadrants of a circle.

Comment: i have a silly question in my mind why you want to make `circle` with border??? we can easily make `circle` with `width` and `height` so why we do with `border`

Comment: FYI, for circle making, use <code>border-radius: 50%</code> - makes it easier to adjust just the width/height when getting your layout right.

Comment: Yes ladies, it's a math

Answer (score 374, accepted):

> How does a border of 180 pixels with height/width-> 0px become a circle with a radius of 180 pixels?

Let's reformulate that into two questions:

### Where do `width` and `height` actually apply?

Let's have a look at the areas of a typical box ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-background-20120724/#corners)):

[image: W3C: Areas of a typical box]

The `height` and `width` apply only on content, if the correct box model is being used (no quirks mode, no old Internet Explorer).

### Where does `border-radius` apply?

The `border-radius` applies on the border-edge. If there is neither padding nor border it will directly affect your content edge, which results in your third example.

### What does this mean for our border-radius/circle?

This means that your CSS rules result in a box that only consists of a border. Your rules state that this border should have a maximum width of 180 pixels on every side, while on the other hand it should have a maximum radius of the same size:

[image: Example image]

In the picture, the *actual content* of your element (the little black dot) is really non-existent. If you didn't apply any `border-radius` you would end up with the green box. The `border-radius` gives you the blue circle.

It gets easier to understand if you apply the `border-radius` [only to two corners](http://jsfiddle.net/9qvgG/):

```
#silly-circle{
    width:0; height:0;
    border: 180px solid red;
    border-top-left-radius: 180px;
    border-top-right-radius: 180px;
}
```

[image: Border only applied on two corners]

Since in your example the size and radius for all corners/borders are equal you get a circle.

### Further resources

#### References

- W3C: [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-background-20120724/) (esp. [5. Rounded Corners](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-background-20120724/#corners))

#### Demonstrations

- Please open the demo below, which shows how the `border-radius` affects the border (think of the inner blue box as the content box, the inner black border as the padding border, the empty space as the padding and the giant red border as the, well, border). Intersections between the inner box and the red border would usually affect the content edge.

```js
var all = $('#TopLeft, #TopRight, #BottomRight, #BottomLeft');

all.on('change keyup', function() {
  $('#box').css('border' + this.id + 'Radius', (this.value || 0) + "%");
  $('#' + this.id + 'Text').val(this.value + "%");
});

$('#total').on('change keyup', function() {
  $('#box').css('borderRadius', (this.value || 0) + "%");
  $('#' + this.id + 'Text').val(this.value + "%");
  all.val(this.value);
  all.each(function(){$('#' + this.id + 'Text').val(this.value + "%");})
});
```

```css
#box {
  margin:auto;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 100px solid red;
  padding: 32px;
  transition: border-radius 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-radius 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius 1s ease;
  -o-transition: border-radius 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-radius 1s ease;
}
#chooser{margin:auto;}
#innerBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <div id="innerBox"></div>
</div>
<table id="chooser">    
  <tr>
    <td><label for="total">Total</label></td>
    <td><input id="total" value="0" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" /></td>
    <td><input readonly id="totalText" value="0" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="TopLeft">Top-Left</label></td>
    <td><input id="TopLeft" value="0" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" /></td>
    <td><input readonly id="TopLeftText" value="0" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="TopRight">Top right</label></td>
    <td><input id="TopRight" value="0" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" /></td>
    <td><input readonly id="TopRightText" value="0" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="BottomRight">Bottom right</label></td>
    <td><input id="BottomRight" value="0" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" /></td>
    <td><input readonly id="BottomRightText" value="0" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="BottomLeft">Bottom left</label></td>
    <td><input id="BottomLeft" value="0" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" /></td>
    <td><input readonly id="BottomLeftText" value="0" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <caption><code>border-radius</code> values. All values are in percent.</caption>
</table>
<p>This demo uses a box with a <code>width/height</code> of 32px, a <code>padding</code> of 32px, and a <code>border</code> of 100px.</p>
```

Comment: I don't think css3-background makes any references to css3-box (css3-box is pending a rewrite).

Comment: @BoltClock: I thought that css3-box would define the _edges_. There's only a reference to css2.1-box in the introduction (non-normative), and the given image is also there, so css3-box isn't really needed to understand `border-radius` (what changes are to expect in the rewrite of css3-box?).

Comment: @Zeta i have a silly question in my mind why you want to make `circle` with border??? we can easily make `circle` with `width` and `height` so why we do with `border`

Comment: @Sarfaraz: Have a look at the OP's question: *"So, how does a border of 180px with `height/width-> 0px` becomes a circle with a radius of 180px?"*. I simply answered the question. There are other ways to create a circle, but OP was only interested how this specific method works.

Comment: @Zeta: I'm not sure what exactly will be changed, but given that that WD hasn't been updated in 6 years, I suspect a lot of it will be. I do know that section 11 (`overflow` family of properties) now lives in its own module, css-overflow-3, but that hasn't been reflected in the ED yet. You'll see plenty of issues in the ED, but I imagine it isn't an exhaustive list: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-box

Comment: @Zeta yup i understand the question and i know what he is asking but this question is in my mind so i ask it i was supposed that something behind this trick etc like that but thanks for answer i like your answer

Answer (score 94):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xJVqy/132/)

Let's examine the question in another way with this picture demonstration:

## Let's see first how border radius is produced?

To produce radius it takes two sides of its border. If you set border-radius to 50 pixels then it would take 25 pixels from one side and 25 pixels from another side.

[image]

And taking 25 pixels from each side it would produce like this:

```
div{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 180px solid red;
    border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

[image]

## Now see how much can it take maximum of square to apply on one corner?

It can take up to 180 pixels from top and 180 pixels from right. Then it would produce like this:

```
div{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 180px solid red;
    border-radius: 0 180px 0 0;
}
```

[image]

## And see this how does it produce if we set non-equal value of radius?

Suppose, if you apply border radius only to two corners unequally:

- top-right-corner to 180 pixels
- bottom-right-corner to 100 pixels

Then it would take

- top-right: 90 pixels from the top and 90 pixels from the right
- bottom-right: 50 pixels from the right and 50 pixels from the bottom

Then it would produce like this

```
div{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 180px solid red;
    border-radius: 0 180px 100px 0;
}
```

[image]

## How much maximum of its border can it take of square to apply on all sides? And see how does it produce a circle?

It can take up to half of the border-size, that is, 180 pixels / 2 = 90 pixels. Then it would produce a circle like this

```
div{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 180px solid red;
    border-radius: 180px;
}
```

[image]

## Why does it take only half of the square to apply on all sides?

Because all corners have to set their radius value equally.

Taking equal parts of its border, it produces a circle.

Comment: Actually the current version of this answer takes it a little bit to far. The question is simply "how does this CSS create a circle", not "how does border-radius work in general", so while technically correct it's a little bit to much. Also you could reformat the question and put actual code into code environments.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it initially creates rectangle with `height and width = 180px` and then make curve with given radius like `30px` with each corner.
So it sets `border` with given `radius`.

Answer (score 3):

Borders are the outer box of any content and if you apply radius on it, it will simply produce the circular edge.

Answer (score 1):

Both `.a` and `.b` will give the identical output.

Q. Why did I used `width: 360px; height: 360px;`?

A. `border: 180px solid red;` in `.a` works like `border-width: 180px 180px 180px 180px; /* Top Right Bottom Left */`.

Hope [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24mtF/) helps you to understand the concept.

```
.a{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 180px solid red;
    border-radius: 180px;
}
.b{
    background:red;
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    border-radius: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Huh? "How does .a work?" "Here's a comparison between .a and .b" I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.