# How do i have a div backround have a rounded corner?

Tags: html, css

How do i have this code have rounded corners? Is that possible?
Also will only the first `<div>` be this color or will it be all `<div>` codes?

```
div {
    background-color:#b0c4de;
}
```

Comment: Maybe related: [How does this CSS produce a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189208/how-does-this-css-produce-a-circle)

Comment: use google.. sorry but that's probably the appropriate answer..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to div:

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

It will apply to all divs. Use ids or classes to refer to specific divs.