# cirular image inside a bootstrap column on a non square image file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image I want to have a circular effect (the original image is rectangular, and I want it to be round - a typical profile image)
Found many sources for this.

The catch is I want to have it inside a bootstrap column and have the `img-responsive` effect

I got really messed up trying to achieve it

Comment: I found solution here. Check it once.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445276/how-to-turn-images-into-circle-shape-bootstrap-3

Comment: well - I found smarter solutions that don't involve forcing the image to be square. But they don't work well with image responsive...

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap already has a class for that: `img-circle`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

**Edit: Not valid for non-square images, sorry**

Comment: and it's creates an ellipse if the image is not square

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this [DEMO?](http://jsfiddle.net/zznv3qqe/) I think it can be achived by setting your image as a `background-image` and defining a `border-radius` which is equivalent to the diameter of your circle.

You will also have to make use of media queries as is always the case when building a responsive design.

The following is a sample as shown in the fiddle:

CSS

```
.circle{
height:150px;
width:150px;
background-image:url("http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/3170bee8-985c-47bc-bbb5-2bcb41e85fe9/d8aa4750-deef-44ac-83a1-f2b5e6ee029a.jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
border-radius:150px;
margin:0 auto;
```

}

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
```

Comment: yeah... but it's not really responsive. It stays 150x150 no matter how you change the browser (and on really narrow ones - it is too big)

Comment: You will have to make use of media queries to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a new css class for the image,

for example.
If you are giving css class "img-circle" for the particular image the property should be af following for the css class.

```
.img-circle{
  border-radius:50%;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
}
```