# How to Circumscribe a square in a circle CSS

Tags: css

Trying to achieve this

[image: square in a circle with edges touching sides]

Forgot too much math to remember how to achieve this.

any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: and here is for the inscribed circle: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63401655/8620333

Comment: awesome thanks, tried looking around for it but couldn't find anything